# Exporting files from Livelink using Java (LAPI.jar)

Tags: livelink

I need to connect to the LiveLink server using a java utility. The LAPI(LiveLink API) is not available over the net   . Can anyone tell me how to connect to it. Can we connect using URLConnection? Or if the LAPI is available somewhere, please let me know.